# Can we have chrome Apps for tablets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I was wondering if we can have chrome apps on tablet and mobile? They are used on desktop version of chrome but I dont know if it works for tablets or mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

No in the sense that an app cannot be straight up loaded in Chrome for mobile. It needs to be published as a separate app in the app store.

Yes in the sense that there is a conversion process developers can use. There's a Google-provided [toolchain](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) based on [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) which allows you to make a native app for mobile out of a Chrome app.

See [here](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/README.md) for the workflow. Note that it is considered a preview release.

Edit: there's an alpha release of a tool which allows to load up an app without conversion. See [Chrome Apps Developer Tool](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/ChromeADT.md)

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks!  Just going to add, the Chrome Apps Developer Tool is meant to help you try your app on your own development device (so you can fix issues and iterate quickly without full builds), but you cannot ship your app to users that way.